# NAudio splitting wav file issue. Every other audio file sound distorted while the others are clear

Tags: wav, naudio

The code in the image below takes a wav file, reads the wav file into memory, finds the length of the wav file, splits the wav file into equal segments, and writes the wav segment to a new wav file.  For some reason, the 2nd, 4th, 6th, 8th, 10th, etc.. files sound distorted and the others sound perfect.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your `sizeOfEachFile` is an odd number. It must be an exact multiple of the `BlockAlign` of the `WaveFormat` which will be 2 in your case for mono 16 bit audio.

Comment: That's exactly what it was.. Thank you!